# bsc node lags behind the network

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc

bsc full nodes often lags behind the network. it's freezes and then starts to catch up. both nodes are running on nvme.

**what the problem looks like:**
the node stops syncing while the network height grows, then the node starts to catch up with the network
[image]

**node1 config:**

```
DatabaseCache = 8192
MaxPeers = 150
--cache 20480 
--syncmode full
```

**node2 config:**

```
DatabaseCache = 8192
MaxPeers = 200
--cache 20480 
--snapshot=false 
--syncmode fast
```

**log before problem:**

```
T05:54:02+0000 lvl=info msg="Imported new chain segment"
T05:54:02+0000 lvl=info msg="Unindexed transactions"
T05:54:04+0000 lvl=info msg="Submitted transaction"
T05:54:06+0000 lvl=info msg="Imported new chain segment"
T05:54:06+0000 lvl=info msg="Unindexed transactions"
T05:54:08+0000 lvl=info msg="Imported new chain segment"
T05:54:08+0000 lvl=info msg="Unindexed transactions"
T05:54:14+0000 lvl=info msg="Downloader queue stats"
T05:54:20+0000 lvl=info msg="Deep froze chain segment"
T05:54:55+0000 lvl=info msg="Submitted transaction"
T05:55:12+0000 lvl=info msg="Submitted transaction"
T05:55:16+0000 lvl=info msg="Submitted transaction"
T05:55:29+0000 lvl=info msg="Submitted transaction"
T05:55:38+0000 lvl=info msg="Submitted transaction"
T05:55:39+0000 lvl=info msg="Persisted trie from memory database"
T05:55:39+0000 lvl=info msg="Imported new chain segment"
T05:55:39+0000 lvl=info msg="Downloader queue stats"
T05:55:39+0000 lvl=info msg="Unindexed transactions"
T05:55:40+0000 lvl=info msg="Imported new chain segment"
```

It's the same for both nodes. does anyone else have same problem? could you help please?